# Can do PHP "write" or "copy" on mounted remote share, but not an "unlink" or "rename" ("Access is denied")

Tags: php, iis, unc

I guess I need a better understanding of WHY this is not working:

I have an existing PHP script where I use the "exec" command to issue a "net use", passing in a service username and password, so as to mount a UNC file share on our internal network here to a drive letter.

The script, historically, has been used only to then read the files in a couple key directories that we want to look at on that share.   I added the ability to create new, empty files successfully (via "fopen") last week.

But now I need to be able to delete, or rename those files via PHP script. (But I haven't tried saving new information into them yet.)

Anytime I try the PHP "unlink" or "rename" command, I get the error:  "Access is denied"

I thought perhaps the service account that has mounted the drive was at fault, because if I look at the ownership on the files that it has created, it says the service user owns them.

So, I changed that account to being my own.  I KNOW I have full permission on any files in the key directory that I'm testing.  However, that didn't change anything.

I found some references here to do a "whoami" command from the script. Well, I did that, one line before attempting an "unlink", and it says it's the IIS user.

So, I'm not sure if it really IS the IIS user that's attempting the "unlink"...and if so, then why did the file get created as the service user and not the IIS user?     Or is something else going on here?

I don't have Admin rights on the server where these files exist, so I can't go over there and fiddle with users and permissions or even look at logs... otherwise, I'd be doing that next.

I guess I'm just stymied by the fact that...whatever user is being used... it can create a file, but it can't delete it or rename it?  Seems like WRITE permission is the key requirement for all of that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Windows permissions are different than linux permissions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx "Giving a user permission to write to a file but not to delete it doesn't prevent the user from deleting the file's contents. A user can still delete the contents." Write will let you empty the file but not remove it. You'll need "Full Modify" or "Execute" to delete the file.

Comment: Ah, bugger.  OK, thanks for clarifying that!

Now, I just have to find a way to get this one script to "impersonate" me or another user like me (several of us have full rights on these directories) when issuing delete commands.  THAT may not be possible, given how we've got this thing rigged-up.